# Consider the homomorphism from A5 to Z_60. Show that the kernel is equal to A5.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know that A5 is simple, and thus it has no non-trivial, proper subgroups. So the kernel must either be {e} or all of A5. But how do I show it's equal to A5/not equal to the trivial subgroup?

Comment: Simplicity doesn't mean that the group has no proper nontrivial subgroups. It says it has no proper nontrivial _normal_ subgroups. It does have nontrivial subgroup, e.g. one isomorphic to $A_4$.

Comment: What's the homomorphism?  Note:  $|A_5|=60$ so were the kernel trivial, this homomorphism would actually be an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

If the kernel were the trivial subgroup then we would have $A_5 \cong Z_{60}$ (by the first isomorphism theorem and the fact that they have the same cardinality).